# How to join/union queries

Tags: mysql

I have a quick problem that i cant find answer to.

```
(SELECT Student_Name AS 'First two from Quiz' FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Quiz' ORDER BY Student_Name LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Student_Name as 'Last two from Quiz' FROM (SELECT Student_Name FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Quiz' ORDER BY Student_Name DESC LIMIT 2) as q ORDER BY Student_Name)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Student_Name as 'Last two from Sqlizer' FROM (SELECT Student_Name FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Sqlizer' ORDER BY Student_Name DESC LIMIT 2) as w ORDER BY Student_Name)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Student_Name AS 'First two from Sqlizer' FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Sqlizer' ORDER BY Student_Name LIMIT 2)
```

Here's a little code of mine. And i need to display them one to another. Like one next to the other. It displays all in one column because of union all. Do you have an idea on the solution to that problem? Please, this is on a matter of time. I'd like to finish it in 2 hours.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Possibly, expected output and real could help

Comment: There is no need for that. The question has already been anwsered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is a more elegant solution, but this is the one I  had time to come up with. You could just use a join to put the tables side by side, but that would give you all possible permutations of the data, which we don't want. So I added a counter to each of the four tables and only output one permutation of the data (the one where the counters are all equal):

```
SELECT a.Student_Name AS 'First two from Quiz', b.Student_Name as 'Last two from Quiz', c.Student_Name as 'Last two from Sqlizer', d.Student_Name AS 'First two from Sqlizer'
FROM
(SELECT  @s:=@s+1 serial_no, Student_Name FROM events, (select @s:=0) as s WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Quiz' ORDER BY Student_Name LIMIT 2) as a,
(SELECT  @s1:=@s1+1 serial_no, t2.Student_Name FROM (SELECT Student_Name FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Quiz' ORDER BY Student_Name DESC LIMIT 2) as t2, (select @s1:=0) as s) as b,
(SELECT  @s2:=@s2+1 serial_no, t3.Student_Name FROM (SELECT Student_Name FROM events WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Sqlizer' ORDER BY Student_Name DESC LIMIT 2) as t3, (select @s2:=0) as s) as c,
(SELECT  @s3:=@s3+1 serial_no, Student_Name FROM events, (select @s3:=0) as s WHERE Event_Name LIKE 'Sqlizer' ORDER BY Student_Name LIMIT 2) as d

WHERE a.serial_no = b.serial_no and c.serial_no = d.serial_no and b.serial_no = c.serial_no
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! I appreciate your fast response! Thank you one more time. Have a good day

Comment: @J.Borrow I am glad I was able to help you. If you like the answer, it would help if you could give it an upvote and accept it as solution.